# VPN connection disables automatic schedules on my tasks

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I have created a task using automation anywhere to run automatically at specified times and the schedule kicks off well until i logon to the machine remotely using vpn access, when  i start loging on to the machine using the vpn my automatic schedules stops working after that, what could be the cause of this issue and how do i resolve it? the machine currently runs windows 7 enterpise.

Kind Regards,

Reuben Kekana

Answer (score 0):

Given your information, the first thing that comes to mind:

When you log into the environment hosting the bot, you essentially 'steal' the connection from the AA control room. When you then disconnect from the environment, neither you nor the control room have an active session to this environment. This in effect means the environment 'logs off' and thus no longer runs any scheduled tasks.

You would need to go to the control room and re-establish this connection.